# Akka and watching a variable with a Future

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-io

A Tcp.OuttgoingConnection gathers data from an audio mixer and is send async to a sourceQueue, which processes the data.

After issuing a command there is no guarantee the next bit of data is the response. How can I feed back the response?

A 'dirty' way would be to have a static variable in which I put the data when processed with a Thread pause to wait for it but that is very inefficient. Is there an akka mechanism that can watch for a value to change and give a Future?

This is the current code:

```
    public Q16SocketThread(ActorSystem system) {
        Logger.debug("Loading Q16SocketThread.");
        this.system = system;

        final Flow<ByteString, ByteString, CompletionStage<Tcp.OutgoingConnection>> connection =
                Tcp.get(system).outgoingConnection(ipAddress, port);

        int bufferSize = 10;
        final SourceQueueWithComplete<ByteBuffer> sourceQueue =
                Source.<ByteBuffer>queue(bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.fail())
                        .map(input -> Hex.encodeHexString(input.array()))
                        .to(Sink.foreach(this::startProcessing))
                        .run(system);

        final Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> repl =
                Flow.of(ByteString.class)
                        .map(ByteString::toByteBuffer)
                        .map(sourceQueue::offer)
                        .map(
                                text -> {
                                    //Logger.debug("Server: " + Hex.encodeHexString(text.array()));
                                    String hexCmd;
                                    if (!nextCmd.isEmpty()) {
                                        hexCmd = nextCmd.take();
                                    } else {
                                        hexCmd = "fe";
                                    }
                                    return ByteString.fromArray(Hex.decodeHex(hexCmd));
                                }).async();

        CompletionStage<Tcp.OutgoingConnection> connectionCS = connection.join(repl).run(system);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, message -> {
                    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                        Logger.debug("Q16 thread started.");
                        nextCmd.put(sysExHeaderAllCall + "1201F7");
                    } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                        Logger.debug("Stopping of data gathering");
                        nextCmd.put(sysExHeaderAllCall + "1200F7");
                        //self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());
                    } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("version")){
                        Logger.debug("Requesting version.");
                        nextCmd.put(sysExHeaderAllCall + "1001F7");
                    }
                }).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand by watching a variable as using the ask pattern and receive a message. In your case you want the message wraped in a Future. Is it what you mean?

If so this from the Akka docs (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/futures.html#use-with-actors)   may help:

There are generally two ways of getting a reply from an AbstractActor: the first is by a sent message (actorRef.tell(msg, sender)), which only works if the original sender was an AbstractActor) and the second is through a Future.

Using the ActorRef’s ask method to send a message will return a Future. To wait for and retrieve the actual result the simplest method is:

```
import akka.dispatch.*;
import jdocs.AbstractJavaTest;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.concurrent.Await;
import scala.concurrent.Promise;
import akka.util.Timeout;

Timeout timeout = Timeout.create(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actor, msg, timeout);
String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

Comment: That is what I use. But the problem is that to know if the operation was successful and to feedback the information is in a process that runs async with the ask request and future. So I do need to leave a little time for the result to be processed before I can return the result. I am wondering how I can do that without pausing the thread.